# Iphone 6 doesn't resize my app while auto layout is turned off

Tags: ios, autolayout, screen-size

I have an app made for iphone 5 screen size. I don't want to use auto layout so i turned it off.
I just want the iphone 6 to resize the content by default.

What should i do, with  auto layout turned my app look like this in different sizes :

[image: different screen aspect]

Comment: Remove launch image for iPhone 6/6 plus and launch screens from your project if added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove launch image for iPhone 6/6 plus and launch screens from your project if added and there is no need to turn off Autolayout , it does not depend on that.!